# getting 2 JSON arrays from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel

I returned from PHP array with two elements through JSON , but the " data.length " does not work . How can I get the size of the array in JS ? If I turn it to one of the elements in the array ( data.name.length ) returns the number of elements in STRING .

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++) {


        $img_name ['id'] = $get_img_id[$i]['id'];

        $img_name ['name'] = $get_img_id[$i]['id'];


    }

     return json_encode($img_name);
```

js:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "upimage",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
       success: function(data) { 

        //$.each(data, function(i) {



          $("#all_files").val(data + " ,");

          for ( var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++ ) {



             $(".returns_img").append("<div class='img_ls' id='" + i + "'><img src='/img/" + data['name'][i] + "'><button class='dell_img' id='"+ i +"'>מחק</button><br><button class='add_img' id='"+ i +"'>הוסף לכתבה</button></div>"); 

            }




      }, 

        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning not array, but a single object from php code, to get what you need try this:

```
        $result = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $result; $i++) {
            $img_name ['id'] = $get_img_id[$i]['id'];
            $img_name ['name'] = $get_img_id[$i]['id'];
            $result[] = $img_name;
        }
        return json_encode($result);
```

Comment: In Js how I came up to the array ? Thank you

Comment: @user3581731 in js your loop is correct, but to get access to each item name just use `data[i].name` (not `data['name'][i]`). BTW learn how to debug JS, its very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
var arr = [], len;

for(key in data) {
    arr.push(key);
}

len = arr.length;
console.log(len)
```